# Kalman filter, defining the measurement model

Tags: kalman-filters

I would like to implement a Kalman filter to estimate the velocity and position of an object. I have an accelerometer, therefore the acceleration is known. The approach is same as:

[Kalman filter for position and velocity: introducing speed estimates](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8860/more-on-kalman-filter-for-position-and-velocity)

however, I don't understand well, how I should define the measurement model:

$\hat{X}(k+1) = \hat{X}(k) + K * ( y(k) - H*\hat{X}(k) );$

K is the kalman gain and is calculated in every step, but What is my "y" here, i know it is called the observations, but how i have my observations ? should i calculate the:

$v(k+1) = a(k)*t + v(k);$

$x(k+1) = 0.5*a(k)*t^2 + v(k)*t +x(k);$

Thank you!

Comment: This  might help http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/estimating-velocity-from-known-position-and-acceleration?lq=1

Comment: @Peter K  would you please take a look at my question ? thank you

Comment: $y$ is given by this equation: $y_k = H*x_k + v_k$. Therefore you need to define the matrix $H$ first, which is the observation matrix. In the wikipedia example (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Example_application.2C_technical) your $y_k$ is called $z_k$. So I suggest you to have a look at that example

Comment: @Rhei thank you very much, my problem is exactly here, i defined H, but i have some doubts to use the x. Are they my own measurements ? as an example here i have the acceleration from accelerometer and from this acceleration i can calculate the velocity and distance. Therefore, the measurements/observations would be velocity and distance by the mentioned formulas ? Im so confused at this point

Comment: No, the observation is what you know of your system, therefore it is the acceleration since you measured it. Velocity and position are what you are trying to estimate

Comment: @Rhei ok in that case what will be ( y(k) - H*Xhat(k) ) because H*X will be equal to y ? am i right ?

Comment: When you compute $y_k-H\hat{x}_k$ you are actually computing the difference between your observation (i.e. mesurements) and an estimate of the observation...in other words, you are updating the estimate using the measurements $y_k$. It is a sort of correction of your estimate based on your measurements

Comment: @Rhei you taught me kalman filter :) thank you very much, i appreciate very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your observation are the $y_k$ your observation model is defined by $Y_k=HX_k+\eta_k$, where $\eta_k$ if a sample from a normal distribution.

If you want your kalman filter to estimate position, velocity and acceleration your state vector is : $X_k=[x_k,\dot{x}_k,\ddot{x}_k]^T$ and therefore your observation matrix is : $H=[0,0,1]$.

As stated by Rhei, your observations are what you get from the system at each time step, i.e. the measured acceleration.