# Defining the observation matrix for a Linear Kalman Filter

Tags: kalman-filters

So I'm working on some content for an exam tomorrow and have hit a logical snag. The question can be seen below:
[image]
In particular I am referring to 5)c).

The questions asks for a measurement model to be derived for this problem.
I am aware that our measurement **Zt = CtXt + noise**, where **Zt** represents the measurement, **Ct** the observation matrix at time t and **Xt** the state vector at time t.

**Xt** is defined as **(Pt, Vt)^T**

One 'solution' I have seen for this problem is to define **Ct** as [1, 0]. However to me this makes little sense. In the question it states we measure **both** the position of the robot *and* the velocity. As such should this observation matrix not be [1,1]? However in which case the result of this multiplication would become = **Pt + Vt**. Which of course is a nonsensical measurement reading.

Instead we want an obersvation matrix defined as:
[image]

As this would give us a **Zt** measurement result of **(Pt, Vt)^T** Which the question asks for?

A similar [question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/22899/kalman-filter-defining-the-measurement-model) has been asked before, however the corresponding solution only adds to my confusion, defining an observation matrix of [0,0,1] thereby resulting in two of the three variables in the defined state vector (for that question) being multiplied by 0 and ignored?

Another [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter?fbclid=IwAR3T7CFQDF9uC5R6zoWnkj0RxtmB8PX9u9XXgUdA9auzkYJOemfVEtITl2U#Example_application.2C_technical) has an almost identical question, but states we measure solely the robots **position** and not both the **position** and **velocity**.

**Question**
Is my thinking right, and therefore the 2x2 identity matrix for the observation matrix correct? Or is there something I am mising?

Answer (score 1):

The first question you link to states that it only measures acceleration and the answer suggests to add the acceleration to the state vector as well, $\begin{bmatrix}x^\top&\dot{x}^\top&\ddot{x}^\top\end{bmatrix}^\top$. This is why the observation matrix becomes $\begin{bmatrix}0&0&I\end{bmatrix}$.

So your reasoning for observation matrix is correct. I only have one remark, namely it is given that the drone moves in 3D space, so the observation matrix should actually be

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
I&0\\0&I
\end{bmatrix}
$$

with $I$ a three by three identity matrix. So effectively the observation matrix would be a six by six identity matrix.