# Kalman filter equations/code to estimate velocity from known position and acceleration

Tags: filters, kalman-filters

I was reading [this post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/estimating-velocity-from-known-position-and-acceleration/50422#50422) and I have the same problem: I want to estimate the velocity using displacement and acceleration measures.

But the problem is that I don't know how I have to code/implement an algorithm using the matrices of Kalman filter presented in the post because there isn't equations with the matrices **H**, **A**, **P**, **Q**, **R**, ... And also the nomenclature from one post to other is different... It is the first time I need to use a Kalman filter, so I am not familiar with the use of this filter.

```
% data(:,1) Time
ts = data(2,1)-data(1,1);
ts2 = ts^2/2;
ts3 = ts^3/6;

nsamples = length(data);
x0 = mean(data(:,3));


ak = data(:,2)./(0.0991/9.81);       % Acceleration
dk = (data(:,3)-x0)./0.1266*2/1000;  % Displacement


% EXAMPLE MATRICES
HH = [1 0 0 0;
      0 0 1 0];

RR = [0.0100     0;
        0     0.0025];

AA = [1 ts ts2  ts3;
      0  1  ts  ts2;
      0  0   1   ts;
      0  0   0    1]; 

PP = [0 0 0   0;
      0 0 0   0;
      0 0 0   0;
      0 0 0 0.001];  

QQ = [0 0 0   0;
      0 0 0   0;
      0 0 0   0;
      0 0 0 0.001]; 


% Current state estimate
xk = [];
xk_prev = [dk(1); 0; ak(1); 0];

%        Disp           Velocity     Acc                   Jerk
xtrue = [ dk;  zeros(nsamples-1,1);   ak;   zeros(nsamples-1,1)];

% Buffers for later display
xk_buffer = zeros(4,nsamples);
xk_buffer(:,1) = xk_prev;
Z_buffer = zeros(1,nsamples);

for k = 1:nsamples-1 
    Z = xtrue(k+1);
    Z_buffer(k+1) = Z;

    P1 = AA*PP*AA' + QQ; 
    S = HH*P1*HH' + RR;

    K = P1*HH'/S; % inv(S)
    P = P1 - K*HH*P1;

    xk = AA*xk_prev + K*(Z-HH*AA*xk_prev);
    xk_buffer(:,k+1) = xk;

    % For the next iteration
    xk_prev = xk;    
end
```

(the language program used is MATLAB)

Comment: Hi! Kalman filters are one of the most complex (both in theory and in practice) linear (and nonlinear with linearization) estimators out there. You better make some theoretical preparation for developing a sense of its principles and its internal behaviour. And you shall also see some working clear code examples. For these two purposes I believe an optimum entrance could be achieved through the book "Fundamentals of Kalman Filtering" from Paul Zarchan. Eventhough this site is not a book suggestion place, your possible state of DSP experience makes it a favorable answer though.