# Position Kalman Filter fails to track a constant-acceleration path

Tags: discrete-signals, kalman-filters, control-systems

I'm trying to build a discrete Kalman Filter that fuses accelerometer (acceleration) and GPS (position, velocity) measurements. However, I'm finding that my filter can't properly track a constant-acceleration path:

[image]
As seen in the top right graph, the difference between the filtered and actual x-positions has a ramping bias, and the variance of the residual noise also increases over time.

My implementation uses the following standard signal model:

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \Delta t \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},
\quad
B = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}\Delta t^{2}\\
\Delta t
\end{pmatrix},
\quad
C = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\quad
D = \begin{pmatrix}
0\\0
\end{pmatrix}$

$x_{n+1}=Ax_{n}+Bu_{n}$

$y_{n} = Cx_{n}+Du_{n}$

Where $x = (r_x,v_x)^{T}$, the measurement $y=x$ uses the GPS position/velocity readings, $\Delta t$ is the sample time and the accelerometer reading is used as the control input $u$. My $Q$ and $R$ matrices are both constant, reflecting each sensor's minimum rated accuracy.

Is this poor tracking behavior to be expected, or is there something wrong with my implementation? I also understand that several other alternative signal models can be used for this problem - for example, using the acceleration as a [observable state instead of a control input](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3292/estimating-velocity-from-known-position-and-acceleration?lq=1). I've tried implementing this model too, but the filtered result is even noisier than what's shown above. Is one of these models more suitable over the other, and why?

Comment: You probably implemented it incorrectly. What does your covariance matrix look like at the end?

Comment: I'm using Simulink for the implementation so I hope the block diagram will suffice: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfhBU.png.


You can see the entries of the optimal covariance matrix in the bottom right - they're symmetric but not quite diagonal. The matrix norm (sqrt of the sum of squared entries) quickly decays to a small but nonzero value: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vvp8.png

Comment: @jd9610, Any chance you share set of data? We'll be able to give you a full solution on your exact data.

Comment: Sure, I'd be happy to. Will the simulink file be good enough? [I've uploaded it here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/168MpAAra_Y-SIiY37hLyNjLTDPXACz-5/view).

Comment: You probably have a mismatch in the time step size. How is the solver configured in your simulink model settings?

Comment: Interesting... I had the settings on auto, so it always chose _variableStepDiscrete_ with a max step size of 0.01 (that being my KF's sample time). The problem disappears when I switch to _fixedStepDiscrete_ with step size 0.01, but reappears if I use a smaller fixed step size. I don't really understand why this happens though?

Comment: Your Kalman filter updates the estimate every simulation time step. However if this time step does not match the time step used for your A and B matrices then your model does not match the dynamics of the generated input signal.

Comment: I see, so does this mean the KF block's internally set sample time is ignored? Also, what happens if I combine it with e.g. a 3DOF quadcopter model model with continuous dynamics? Is the fixed-step solver my only option for solving the full system?

Comment: I am not sure if I have ever combined a continuous system with a discrete system in Simulink, so I am uncertain about this as well. However I suspect that you would have to use a fixed time step solver.

Comment: @jd9610 one possibly is your implementation, or actually the reference you used. some authors don’t cover the case where you have a deterministic forcing function in their Kalman Filter functions. One of Bar Shallom’s text assumes that the modification is trivial. He actually had a homework problem where you needed to modify his filter equations to get the filter to track.