# Applying Kalman filter to a data set

Tags: kalman-filters

I went through the answer [Kalman filter in practice](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3255/kalman-filter-in-practice) and it seems we must know all the first and second order properties of random variables to apply the Kalman filter.

But when I only have a set of data $y_1,\dots,y_n$ and a given model $G$ and $F$ with assumed noise processes, could someone please explain to me how to apply Kalman filter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Signal Model**

The first thing you really need when you start to use a Kalman filter is what I would call the "signal model".  That means, you need to take a guess (and sometimes that's all it is, though usually you can have an *educated* guess) at how the signal you're measuring, $y$, was generated.

The usual signal model comprises $F$, $G$, $H$, $Q$ and $R$:

$$
x_{k+1} = F x_k + G u_k + w_k\\
y_k = H x_k + v_k
$$

where $Q$ is the covariance of $w_k$ and $R$ is the covariance of $v_k$.

**What are you trying to achieve?**

Implicit in the signal model is that you've chose the "state variables" (the components of $x_k$) that you are working with.  Usually, what you are trying to achieve is to measure something and, from that, infer the value of one or more of the state variables.

**What's missing?**

Based on what you've said, the only thing that seems to be missing is how you get from the states $x_k$ to your measurements $y$ (i.e. $H$).

Comment: Are the $x_k$s and $y_k$s random variables? or are they specific samples of those random variables? When I read the book I feel like they develop the theory for random variables not for smaples. But in my application I only have a data set no random variables. Thanks

Comment: $y_k$ are your measurements, your data. I'm not sure I understand your confusion.  Measurements *are* random variables. Data sets *are* random variables.

Comment: My confusion is, I think a measurement is just one instance of a random variable. But random variable is the whole possible range. That is my confusion. Like $Y_k$ can take any value in it's range and $y_k$ is just the one we observed at that particular trial. They develop the theory for $Y_k$s but in practice we only have $y_k$s. I hope I made clear my confusion, many thanks for trying to help me understand it.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the clarification.  The data, as you say, is just one realization of the random process, $Y_k$. However, that's all you need: the KF is developed for the random variables, but the equations apply to any particular realization of the process, $y_k$.